# How to get value from <h1> tag using class in Selenium WebDriver, Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have html code:

```
<div class="formCaptionContainer fill-width" data-dyn-bind="sizing: { width: $dyn.layout.Size.available }">
<h1 class="formCaption" data-dyn-bind="text: $data.Caption, click: $data.GoGridView">Expense report for Aditi Mehta - GS1-000282, testing2</h1>
<h2 class="formCaption-context" data-dyn-bind="text: $data.ParentTitleFields">Aditi Mehta : GS1-000282</h2>
</div>
```

I want to get the value Expense report for Aditi Mehta - GS1-000282, testing2 from /h1 tag

Any one know how to do it?

I've tried :

```
By.xpath(".//div[@class='formCaption']/h1";
```

Above showing no element found

```
By.className("formCaption");
```

Above showing blank data

```
By.xpath(".//*[@class='formCaption']/h1");
```

Above showing no element found

Comment: try this xpath. "//h1[@class='formCaptain']"

Comment: I tired with the above, showing 'No such element found'

Comment: can you try adding some wait and check?

Comment: Yes I did that too. But either i am getting no such element found or blank data is coming.

Comment: blank text is coming means the xpath is correct. what does this prints., driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[@class='formCaptain']")).getText();

Comment: Got:  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h1[@class='formCaptain']"}

Comment: my bad..., there is an spello in the class value it has to be formCaption instead of formCaptain.

Comment: By headingExpenseText = By.xpath("//h1[@class='formCaption']");                      public String getTitleEx()
 {
  
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  return driver.findElement(headingExpenseText).getText();
 }                                                                                                                  System.out.println("Text is " + objExpenseCreate.getTitleEx());                         It is printing only Text is

Comment: @santhoshkumar I hope you are able to get the above code, I created a page object model. Save value in headingExpenseText. Then create a method of it. And call that method in the test case class.

Comment: Yes, I am. It is supposed to work. If the above is not working, can you check this, webElement.getAttribute("value");

Comment: Where should I use this: webElement.getAttribute("value");?

Comment: instead of driver.findElement(headingExpenseText).getText() use driver.findElement(headingExpenseText).getAttribute("value");

Comment: but my value is dynamic I can't hardcode it. It will get change everytime.

Comment: after giving value it is showing 'Text is null'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you need exactly, Data displayed on web page or textValue used in HTML code?

If your locator is correct , then instead of `getText()`, you can try `getAttibute("innerHTML")` like below,

```
By.xpath("//*[@class='formCaption'][contains(text(),'Aditi Mehta')]").getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider your [locator strategy](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/start.html#locating_elements), the following provide good preferences for general case approach.

- location by ID globally unique elements
- locate by name for page unique elements
- locate by css as catch all case

You should also take a look at the [PageObject pattern](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/guidelines.html#page_object_models).

It appears the page is using a JS library to display the contents through late binding/resolution.  Your test needs allow for this and wait until the page elements you are interested in are fully rendered.  Find out from the developers what the element looks like before it is resolved and afterwards.  Late resolution is one considerations in determining your locator strategy.  The strategy should include fluent waiting and default time-outs for elements to appear.

This is not a problem of fixing a single locator.

Comment: Can you provide me the solution of this, as I've tried so many ways but I am not able to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below Xpath.

```
String msg=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='formCaptionContainer fill-width']/h1[@class='formCaption-context']")).getText();
```

Comment: I tried with above, it is showing Text is    that's it. Not picking the value. I don't know whats the issue.

Comment: Did u try with these also- <WebElement>.getAttribute("innerText") or <WebElement>.getAttribute("textcontent") or  <WebElement>.getAttribute("innerHTML")

Comment: Below code worked for me. you can try this once.                      WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='formCaptionContainer fill-width']/h1"));
  System.out.println(ele.getText());

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me very well

```
       String textprint=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='formCaption-context']")).getText();
        System.out.println(textprint);
```

> Hope It will solve your problem

Comment: No, it is not picking the data. Xpath is correct but data is not printing.Blank data is coming.

Comment: its pick data for me... Use Thread.sleep(3000); before taking XPath.Let see what happen.I tried this code and its print the value perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
String msg= driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[contains(@class='formCaptionContainer')]/h1 ).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared, the node attributes looks dynamic to me. So we have to induce `WebDriverWait` as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[@class='formCaption']"), "Aditi Mehta - GS1-"));
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[@class='formCaption']")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help. It is working fine now. I use the below code

```
By headingExpenseText = By.xpath("//*[@class='formCaption'][contains(text(),'Expense report for')]");

public String getTitleEx()
    {

        return driver.findElement(headingExpenseText).getAttribute("innerHTML");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
String titleElem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='formCaptionContainer fill-width']/h1")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
    assertEquals("Worked", titleElem);
```